# Laravel validation username must not start with specific string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to register user but I want to put validation rule on username that username should not start with special characters and also should not start with `web.` I found regex that work fine special characters but detect the string it give me error of Invalid format

```
return [
          'username' => [
                    'required',
                    'regex:/^\S*$/u',
                    'regex:/^[_]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+([_.-]?[a-zA-Z0-9])*$/',
                    'unique:users'
                ],
          'full_name' => 'required',
       ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this?

```
 return [
          'username' => [
                    'required|
                     not_regex:/^[web_-][a-z_\-0-9]*/i|
                     regex:/^[A-Za-z_ \-0-9]+$/u|
                    unique:users'
                ],
          'full_name' => 'required',
       ];
```

Comment: how about not start with create_ read_ delete_ update_?

Answer (score 0):

This should work as you want it to

```
return [
          'username' => [
                    'required',
                    'regex:/^(?!web)[a-zA-Z]\w+$/',
                    'unique:users'
                ],
          'full_name' => 'required',
       ];
```

Here's a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/L7Q4Eq/1) for you to test it out.